# Is Objective-C under ARC guaranteed to initialize statics and ivars to zero?

Tags: objective-c, initialization, automatic-ref-counting

Looking through the official Transitioning to ARC document from Apple, it says that "stack variables" are now initialized to zero values.  Yet in my quick, informal test, static variables and ivars seem to be initialized to zero as well; and some people express a  belief that they absolutely are automatically zeroed. However static variables and ivars are not stack variables. Did Apple issue a different edict about static variables and ivars?

Also is there a difference between the initialization of a static in a function and a static outside of a function?

Answer (score 2):

`static` vars are zeroed out due to the semantics of the language — as a strict superset of C, the behavior is guaranteed. [ivars are also guaranteed to be zeroed out upon initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ObjectAllocation/ObjectAllocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH7-SW1) (see bullet 3).

Comment: Add to that *ivars are always initialized to zero due to the semantics of the Objective-C language*.  This has been true long before ARC existed, IIRC.

Comment: Then why was Swift sold to us as having the vital feature that it requires all variables to be initialized with a value? Just because zero is sometimes not an ideal value?

Comment: @Q453 - Whether a language should require explicit initialisation/assignment before use (as in Swift) or support default initial values (as in Objective-C) is a philosophical/religious debate with arguments on both sides – which will not be presented here! But for one language implementation's amusing contribution to that debate [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL_68-R#F00L)

Comment: @Q453: As noted in other comments, there's a lot of philosophy to get into there. But to attempt to cover the key Swift differences succinctly: 1) there are "safety" features in ObjC that accreted over time and thus aren't present in all development environments and deployment targets, but are there from the start in Swift, and 2) Swift takes the position that there's a difference between "initialized to a value defined by the language/compiler/runtime" and "initialized to a value defined by the programmer", and enforces the latter.